# Client-side shows data from the last user who connected when reload the page

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, websocket, client-side, actioncable

I'm trying to create a "lobby" where you can join parties and the other user accepts who he wants from the list, i'm using **ActionCable** and **Ruby on Rails**

The incomming requests shows the info from the last user connected on receiving data and must show the info of incomming requests to ours (**not to change our view with the other user data!**).

### That's the js file (coffee)

```
App.join = App.cable.subscriptions.create "JoinChannel",

  connected: ->
    # Called when the subscription is ready for use on the server
  disconnected: ->
    # Called when the subscription has been terminated by the server
  received: (data) ->
    $('#join_list_table').empty()
    this.render_list(data)
    $(".button-collapse").sideNav();
    $(".modal-trigger").click ->
      joinListId = $(this).attr('id')
      App.join.joinTheList joinListId
  # Called when there's incoming data on the websocket for this channel

  joinTheList: (listId) ->
    @perform "join", list_id: listId
    $('.modal').modal opacity: 0
  leave: ->

  render_list: (data) ->
    joinLists = data['joinLists']
    for joinList in joinLists
      joinings = joinList['joinings']
      if joinList['user']['id'] != data['current_user_id'] # here must say if the joinlist have the same id than the user
        $('#join_list_table').append(
          "<tr>
            <td>#{joinList['user']['name']}</td>
            <td>#{joinList['user']['email']}</td>
            <td>#{joinList['user']['language']}</td>
            <td>#{joinList['user']['country_code']}</td>
            <td>#{joinList['user']['price']}</td>
            <td>#{joinList['user']['currency']}</td>
            <td>
              <a class='modal-trigger' id='#{joinList['list']['id']}' href='#modal#{joinList['list']['id']}' >
               Join
              </a>
            </td>
          </tr>
          ")
        $('main').append(
          "<div class='modal z-depth-0' id='modal#{joinList['list']['id']}'>
            <div class='modal-content'>
              <div class='col s12'>
                <ul id='joinings#{joinList['list']['id']}' class='collection with-header'>
                  <li class='collection-header'><h4>Join list for #{joinList['user']['name']}</h4></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>")

        for joining in joinings
          $("#user_#{joining['user']['id']}_joining").remove();
          $("#joinings#{joinList['list']['id']}").append("<li id='user_#{joining['user']['id']}_joining'><a class='collection-item z-depth-0 center-align'>#{joining['user']['name']}</a></li>")
      else
        joinings = joinList['joinings']
        for joining in joinings
          $('#slide-out').append("<li id='user_#{joining['user']['id']}_joining'><a class='collection-item z-depth-0 center-align'>#{joining['user']['name']}</a></li>")
document.addEventListener 'turbolinks:load', ->
  App.join.perform "render_all"
  $('#query').on 'keyup', ->
    value = $(this).val().toLowerCase()
    $('tr').filter ->
      $(this).toggle $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1
```

### That's the ruby file

```
class JoinChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    unless current_user.join_list
      current_user.create_join_list
    end
    stream_from "join_channel"
    render_all
  end

  def unsubscribed
    if current_user.join_list.joinings
      current_user.join_list.joinings.destroy_all
    end
    current_user.join_list.destroy
    # Any cleanup needed when channel is unsubscribed
  end

  def join(data)
    joinlist = JoinList.find(data['list_id'])
    unless current_user.joining
      puts "esta creando"
      current_user.create_joining(join_list_id: joinlist.id)
    else
      puts "esta actualizando"
      current_user.joining.update(join_list_id: joinlist.id)
    end
    render_all
  end
  def render_all
    joinlistArr = []
    joinlists = JoinList.joins(:user)
    joinlists.each do |joinlist|
      joiningusers = []
      joinlist.joinings.each do |joining|
        joiningusers << {'user' => joining.user}
      end
      joinlistArr << {'list' => joinlist, 'user' => joinlist.user, 'joinings' => joiningusers}
    end
    puts "dame los joinings de la joinlist del current_user"
    puts current_user.join_list.joinings
    ActionCable.server.broadcast "join_channel", {joinLists: joinlistArr, current_user_id: current_user.id}
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved!**

Change

```
ActionCable.server.broadcast "join_channel", {joinLists: joinlistArr, current_user_id: current_user.id}
```

**for**

```
JoinChannel.broadcast_to( 
      current_user, 
      joinLists: joinlistArr, 
      current_user_id: current_user.id 
    )
```